# Update procedure Incorrect/ unknown column in entry parameter

Tags: mysql, procedure

I have error with one entry parameter but I dont know why:

```
0   14:31:47    call UpdateComment(66,1,2,"NOWYTitle","NOWYContent")    Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'NOWYTitle' in 'field list'
```

call procedure:

```
call UpdateComment(66,1,2,"NOWYTitle","NOWYContent");
```

my procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS UpdateComment $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `UpdateComment`(UserId INT,/*Crc32 int(11) unsigned,*/ArticleId int(11),CommentsId int(11), newTitle varchar(255), newContent varchar(255))
BEGIN

        DECLARE helpUserTable varchar(255);

        set helpUserTable = CONCAT("User",UserId);

        set @score1 =CONCAT("UPDATE `",helpUserTable,"` SET Title = ",newTitle," WHERE CommentsId = ",CommentsId," AND ArticleId = ",ArticleId);
        PREPARE stmt FROM @score1;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
        set @score2 =CONCAT("UPDATE `",helpUserTable,"` SET Content = ",newContent," WHERE CommentsId = ",CommentsId," AND ArticleId = ",ArticleId);
        PREPARE stmt FROM @score2;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

Comment: OK I now ! Problem is with newTitle exactly: '' must be '",newTitle,"'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Procedure generates these statements:

```
UPDATE `User66` SET Title = NOWYTitle WHERE CommentsId = 2 AND ArticleId = 1

UPDATE `User66` SET Content = NOWYContent WHERE CommentsId = 2 AND ArticleId = 1
```

They are incorrect, because all literals (string values) must be quoted -

```
UPDATE `User66` SET Title = 'NOWYTitle' WHERE CommentsId = 2 AND ArticleId = 1

UPDATE `User66` SET Content = 'NOWYContent' WHERE CommentsId = 2 AND ArticleId = 1
```

So, change code in this way -

```
...
SET @score1 = CONCAT("UPDATE `", helpUserTable, "` SET Title = '", newTitle, "' WHERE CommentsId = ", CommentsId, " AND ArticleId = ", ArticleId);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to add quotes to your command around the text values, and secondly your SQL statements can be combined into one statement (they share the same where clause):

Try this:

```
    set @score1 = CONCAT("UPDATE `", helpUserTable, "` SET Title = '", newTitle, 
        "', Content = '", newContent, "' WHERE CommentsId = ", 
        CommentsId, " AND ArticleId = ", ArticleId);
```

and delete `@score2` altogether